# Retag the [html] + [table] questions to [html-table]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

<s>The excerpt for [table](/questions/tagged/table) reads.</s>

> Tables are used to display tabular data in HTML.

This means that [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) is redundant and should be merged into [table](/questions/tagged/table). Thanks.

---

We should retag all the questions tagged **both** [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [table](/questions/tagged/table) as [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table).

**Note:** This doesn't mean that you should remove [html](/questions/tagged/html). Only the [table](/questions/tagged/table) tag should be retagged as [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table).

Comment: Negative.  Checking tag [tag:table], the first question already doesn't refer to HTML tables.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, they are wrong. As the wiki explicitly mentions to not use the tag when referring to a relational database.

Comment: Someone co-opted the tag wiki.  Doesn't mean they're right.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Doesn't mean they're wrong either.

Comment: I think they are.  There are several possible contexts for [table].

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed. Let's go through table and retag everything appropriately. It will be like retagging [tag:list]. Btw, can we have that marked as [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: Wouldn't removing [tag:html] from these questions hide them from people watching that tag? Unless you plan on leaving [tag:html] and just replacing [tag:table] with [tag:html-table]?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler Clarified concerns.

Comment: Good :-) Now, how do we prevent new questions from being tagged [tag:table] when they should be tagged [tag:html-table]? Hopefully people see it when they type "table", but maybe not. It would just be a shame to do all this work and then have the problem come back.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler With as much things that have been retagged lately, we need some kind of script that automatically checks for this kind of stuff every week to see if the problem returns.

Answer (score 3):

That tag wiki **is not** specific to HTML. The last edit to the excerpt was a bad one.

The part about not using them with relational databases only relates to databases. Tagging things as [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [table](/questions/tagged/table) doesn't make much sense, because it's generally understood that MySQL uses database tables.

I added the HTML parts to it because I knew about them and that tag was very common. It was never meant to convert the tag to be HTML-specific. I would **much rather** see the appropriate HTML questions moved over to [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) because [table](/questions/tagged/table) in itself is very ambiguous.

Comment: That is probably the better option.

Comment: You should leave this unaccepted until the problem is actually fixed, though.

Comment: Okay. I edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler: You don't need to remove the [tag:html] tag as well. It's fine to have them tagged as [tag:html] *and* [tag:html-table].

Comment: Sorry. I meant to comment on the question itself :-( I didn't realized you replied until after I deleted my comment.

Comment: @animuson, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't fit this in a comment...

As the person who suggested the (approved) edit to the excerpt of [table](/questions/tagged/table) I'd just like to explain my reasoning.

To quote from the tag wiki:

> When referring to a relational database, do not use this tag. Use the
>   appropriate tag for the database to which the question refers.

It seemed really rather pointless and counter-productive to have the following in the excerpt:

> In an RDMS, tables contain multiple columns that represent a
>   particular set of data.

I happen to agree with animuson's original edit to the wiki and his answer above. Using the tag [table](/questions/tagged/table) in the context of a relational database is fairly ridiculous. It's more than implied by the fact that a database is being used. I therefore changed the excerpt to exclude mention of databases rather than altering the wiki to indicate that [table](/questions/tagged/table) was appropriate for them.

I, obviously, disagree with the characterisation of the edit to the excerpt as "bad" :-).

Personally, I'm with the OP and animuson on this [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) makes much more sense. If the tag is not meant to related solely to HTML tables (and the tag [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) exists) then the excerpt should, maybe, be changed to something like this?:

> Tables are used to display tabular data. Do not use for HTML-tables or
>   in relation to a RDBMS.

Though *"Tables are used to display tabular data"* is a fairly obvious statement to make.