# Can we start cleaning up [table] tag and burninate it ASAP

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

### Related questions:

1. [Retag the [html] + [table] questions to [html-table]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134678/212576)
2. [Conflicting tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169959/212576) (This led to founding of [lua-table](/questions/tagged/lua-table))

The tag [table](/questions/tagged/table) has become cluttered with all kinds of questions ranging from sql tables (for all DBM systems, HTML tag `<table>`, outputting content in any language (PHP, C#, LaTeX to name a few) as a table and several plugins of various languages and/or IDEs (like jTable, tablesorters and the kind).

The current count stands at **18,315** questions having this ambiguous tag. A few of possible suggestions for cleaning process:

1. [table](/questions/tagged/table) + [html](/questions/tagged/html) to [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table) | [5,011 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table+html)
2. [table](/questions/tagged/table) + [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) to [lua-table](/questions/tagged/lua-table) | [47 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua+table)
3. [table](/questions/tagged/table) + [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) to [database-table](/questions/tagged/database-table) | [2,567 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+table)
4. [table](/questions/tagged/table) + [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) to [database-table](/questions/tagged/database-table) | [99 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+table)
5. [table](/questions/tagged/table) + other-specific-DBM systems to whatever_DBM_it_is-table
6. [table](/questions/tagged/table) + [database](/questions/tagged/database) to [database-table](/questions/tagged/database-table) | [1,152 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database+table)

Since I've no idea about other languages and their specific features regarding table, I'd ask the community for their input on this (such as [C#+table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table+c%23), [python+table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table+python), [android+table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table+android) and [r+table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table+r)). The other questions are either tagged with `arrays` or `sql` and similar tags, and in my opinion, just removing [table](/questions/tagged/table) from such questions would be enough!

Comment: We could do this in a couple minutes with a [fancy tag filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119103/add-a-tag-filter-to-the-merge-tags-dialog), but alas, the hard way is the only method we have. :(

Comment: So, tell me again why `table` + `html` (and all of the other variants) are bad?  The tag is *not* ambiguous; `table` has a single meaning.  If you want a specific type of table, [add another tag to your search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+table), just like you did in your question.

Comment: @animuson: Note that the example provided in that question was for the tag [activity], which can mean almost anything (including Android Activities).  The cleanup for that was quite difficult.

Comment: @Robert How can you be an expert on "tables" when the term "tables" covers so many different things depending on what type of table you're actually referring to? Sure, you *could* be an expert on HTML tables *and* Lua tables, but both of those tables are different things that you can be an expert in, not one. According to the [lua-table tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua-table/info), Lua tables aren't even remotely similar to standard tables and implement associative arrays.

Comment: @animuson The only compelling argument I've ever heard for disambiguating tags this way is that it becomes possible to follow them.  Searching for HTML tables is [not all that difficult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+table).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then what would you call [these ~2000 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+table) or rather, [these 1500](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+table+-html)?

Comment: @hjpotter92: OK, I see your point.  Which disambiguated tag gets `table` as a synonym, so that it is never abused again?

Comment: We should probably *not* create database-specific "table" tags, using purely `database-table`.  TBH I expect that the tag would be just noise on most of those questions anyway ("how can I select this from that table?" doesn't need a freaking `*table` tag)

Comment: @Charles Tag synonimising can be the next step in the process.

Comment: @Charles Very true. Using any sort of database *implies* using a "database table" so any sort of table tag related to a database is useless. Just tag it with the database schema you're using and be done with it.

Comment: By the same logic, can't you say we need to split [tag:list] into [tag:java-list], [tag:c++-list], etc. and [tag:arrays] into [tag:java-arrays], [tag:c++-arrays], etc., etc., etc., ETC!? (this would probably create a few hundred thousand tags, so no, I don't think it's a good idea) And PLEASE NOT [tag:mysql-table], [tag:postgresql-table] or [tag:database-table] as these would apply to roughly 99.99999% of the questions tagged [tag:mysql], [tag:postgresql] or [tag:database] respectively ([tag:table] should just be removed from those questions).

Comment: I just looked through a couple of pages of the 'r'+'table' questions and they are all over the place. Some refer to the table() function or the various libraries that deal with tables, but many are about other r data structure (matrix, data frame) that are wrongly called tables in the question. Still others are are about reading or writing an html table or database table in R. Certainly many of these should be re-tagged. As for keeping table vs. breaking it up into dozens of tags - does anyone really just search on table? On its own it means very little. Is making many new tags so bad?

Comment: @JohnPaul: Are you asserting that the only valid search is a single-tag search?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I don't mean to say that the only valid search is single tag. However, if the choice is that all searches are [table] + [something] (as table alone means little) or adding a bunch of meaningful [table+something] tags with useful tag wikis etc, I don't see what is so bad about the many tag option.

Comment: It really has nothing to do with searching. It has to do with the *purpose of tags*. They're there to categorize things into a single topic that you *can be an expert on*. While tables may be a "single" yet very, very broad topic, it's impossible to be an expert on tables because there are *so many* different tables that require vastly different knowledge. If table meant the same thing everywhere, then there wouldn't be any problem, but database tables are extremely different from HTML tables, extremely different from Lua tables, and extremely different from Android table layouts.

Comment: @animuson I don't disagree with your reasoning, I just think the implications would be far-reaching. I can be the world's most skilled expert at linked-lists, but ask me a linked-list question in a language that's syntax I don't understand and I'll just look at you funny. So we should burninate [tag:list], [tag:arrays], [tag:data-structures], [tag:design-patterns], [tag:algorithm], etc. (or only have these related to [tag:language-agnostic]) and create the respective tags for each language. I hope you don't think we should do that.

Comment: @Dukeling: You could be an expert on how to work with lists and list algorithms without knowing the syntax for implementing lists in all languages. The theory of the list data structures and the algorithms for them are universal and independent of programming languages. Whereas, the table could mean different things depending on the context. So I think we can eliminate the table tag while keeping the list tag.

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated back to MSO?

Comment: Yes, why hasn't this been migrated back to MSO after 4 months??

Comment: @JohnPaul yes, R table could mean [contingency table](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/table) or else a mislabeling for data.table/array/matrix; (or it might even refer to html/JS). So it's not possible to do a bulk retag in the case of R.

Comment: Could you repost this on the SO meta? An editor has been citing it for his tag edits, but it's kind of weird to point to a closed question with zero answers on the wrong site. http://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%E6%B1%A4%E8%8E%B1%E6%81%A9?tab=activity

Comment: Like one of these [DROP TAG table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304218/1575353) or [Can we make the table tag language specific](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280250/1575353)? @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩