# Should this type of tag be deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

I have seen a [table](/questions/tagged/table)  tag and its description and the description says

> This tag is ambiguous. Consider using other tags instead. Read the tag wiki for more information.

[image]

So I think that is because table can be anything,like `HTML table`, `CSS table` or `database table` etc. So it makes ambiguity and only `table` word doesn't make any specific sense.
I would like to say if we are suggesting to don't use this tag, then why should we include that.

And is there any way to restrict for creating such ambiguous tags.

Comment: I faced a similar case with the [**officedev**](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/officedev/info) tag recently. It had no tag wiki at all and it seemed to be misleading a bit. I have submitted a body for the tag and specifically says it's a generalized tag but to use more specific ones. My suggestion actually got accepted by the mods. So, I wouldn't recommend deletion of it maybe editing the body - as I believe that's what the body is for.

Comment: Related (from table info)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198024/can-we-start-cleaning-up-table-tag-and-burninate-it-asap

Comment: One issue with this is that `table`, whilst ambiguous is the **actual name** of a html tag. So it will be used for this purpose almost for definite.