# All tags have left us! (currently only on Meta Stack Overflow)

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, meta

Noticed it just now. When I tried to edit my older question ( [Can we start cleaning up [table] tag and burninate it ASAP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198024/212576) ); I noticed that all occurances of `[tag:xyz]` were being shown as `undefined` instead of [xyz](/questions/tagged/xyz) as shown below.

> [image: img1]

Probably a minor glitch in template editing and would be fixed soon. Just thought I should notify the staff :)

Another thing I noticed was the empty tags-list under the post.

> [image: img2]

It is currently only seen on Meta Stack Overflow and nowhere else.

Comment: PS: I couldn't even add any other tags to the post (this one). It's like all tags have just left.

Comment: *"It's time to play everybody's favourite game: [Wheel ... of ... BLAME!](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)"*

Comment: Our wheel of blame has sound... pfft :-)

Comment: From what I can see the editing itself works, but processing of tags is broken (when you click edit the tags are correctly passed to the tag-editing-thingy, but never processed).

Comment: All your tags are belong to us.

Comment: How can we mark this as [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: I was trying to ask  a question and can't tag it. Probably its because this!

Comment: [According to Oded](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1567544#1567544) it will be fixed soon.

Comment: @Sklivvz - After the next build is released.

Comment: Thank god that we could add at lease one tag. Otherwise we even can't ask a question on Meta for this bug report.

Comment: argh, localization bugs starting to appear in javascript!!!1

Comment: @m0sa are they infectious?

Comment: I just hope the css doesn't get infected

Comment: @m0sa `#undefined, .undefined { undefined: undefined; }` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in the latest meta build. Long live the tags!